# How to Resize an Image within a Scrollview?

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, resize, image-size

I have searched for a while now, and can't find anything that is specific to my problem.

Basically, I have an image of a large map, I want users to be able to zoom in and out, and scroll through the map. I literally have all aspects of the zooming and scrolling working, although when I start up the app, the image (within the scroll view) is massive! The image is a large file (1200x1024) but it has to be so users can zoom right in without any pixelation.

My question is, how can I make it so when I start the app, that image (map) fits to the size of the screen, and then from there, users can zoom in and scroll and etc? Because right now is looks like this when I start up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq1en.png

Thank you heaps!

**Current Code:** (Under the 'FireViewController.m' file)

```
@synthesize scrollView, imageView;

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ returnimageView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"Mezzanine Level"]];
    self.imageView = tempImageView;

    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
   [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
   [scrollView setContentSize:imageView.frame.size];  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Set the initial zoom level of the scroll view to fit the image.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for that. I used 'zoomScale = 0.2', and it sort of works.

Although, it still cuts of some of the images sides. Is there a way to fit the width to the page?

Comment: Sure. Do some math and calculate the proper zoom level based on the image size and visible scroll view size.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, I just figured it out! I changed the zoomScale to .25 and the minimumZoomScale to .25 now it fits perfectly.

One question though, when I do zoom in, and I start scrolling around, the horizontal scroll bar it halfway up the page, and is in the way of the image. How can I make it sit just above the tab bar?
Thanks